# How do I add space for a null char at the end of a character array?

Tags: c++, arrays, c-strings

Currently, my char array does not act like a C-string resulting in some bad memory, and which I'm assuming is to do with the fact that I don't have a null `\0` at the end of it. I've been told I need to "allocate enough space" to do this, but I assumed that was what the "+1" at the end of my declaration of temp was for.

```
DNAStrand DNAStrand::operator+(const DNAStrand& other) const {
    char* temp = new char [strlen(bases) + strlen(other) + 1];
    strcat(temp, this->bases);
    strcat(temp, other.bases);
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't your first `strcat` be a `strcpy`?

Comment: Also in the first line, `other` is not a string; should it be `other.bases`?

Comment: If you are using C++, why use `char[]`? Why not `std::string`?

Comment: And finally, you are returning `temp` which is of type `char *` but the function is supposed to return `DNAStrand`?  Is this your actual code or something that you have mistyped from memory?

Comment: A null character at the end ("null terminator") needs exactly that, one more byte, set to zero, at the end. Your problem must be somewhere else. Have you tried using a debugger and inspecting what exactly is going on? Debuggers are very useful in these situations.

Comment: Initialize `*temp = 0;` after you allocate with `new` and before the first `strcat` so `strcat` knows where the end of `temp` is.

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize the temp after allocating memory. One simple way to do it while using new is add the parentheses. For plain old data POD it will initialize to 0.

```
char* temp = new char [strlen(bases) + strlen(other) + 1]();
```

If you do not initialize the temp could have garbage. e.g. if temp after allocation contains 'ab\0d456546 blah blah'. So the first strcat will assume ab as valid value and start appending after ab. It could have anything.

Comment: Noted M.M and provided more explanation.